# Well-designed wrappers around glm vector library

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, wrapper, glm-math

## [Solved]

This question is so specific that I'm unsure how to search for information, so experience has taught me that it's better to ask a question here than to implement something of sub-optimal quality.

### The problem

I have a game engine, and need to write wrappers around some common vector functionality. I'm using the glm library, but I **do not want to expose glm types** to the rest of the codebase. A bit of inspiration came from a vlog on game engine design ([Travis Vroman: Kohi Game Engine Series #22](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WR0tAQj-og8&list=PLv8Ddw9K0JPg1BEO-RS-0MYs423cvLVtj&index=24)).

- In case I desire to use DirectX at some point, then glm types might not be compatible (I don't know this, but *maybe*).
- If I desire to switch to another linalg library, then having glm types littered all across the codebase is going to be a problem.

### Some working code

I have developed a small working test sample, which should be sufficient to showcase my current level of thinking:

```cpp
// the header
namespace math
{
    template<class T>
    union tvec2
    {
        T elements[2];
        struct
        {
            union { T x, r, s, u; }; // aliases for first element
            union { T y, g, t, v; }; // aliases for second element
        };
    };

    typedef tvec2<float> vec2;

    vec2 operator+(vec2 a, vec2 b);
}

// the source file for glm implementation
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

math::vec2 math::operator+(math::vec2 a, math::vec2 b)
{
    glm::vec2 result = glm::vec2(a.x, a.y) + glm::vec2(b.x, b.y);
    return { result.x, result.y };
}
```

### My intuition

**Static storage requirements**:
I want the storage requirements of a `vec2` to be static and present inside the header. This makes it easy to obtain better cache performance by packing vectors inside arrays of structs. Otherwise I would have to use either interfaces or opaque pointer types which would both lead to additional runtime indirections. I can think of other reasons, but hopefully this intuition is clear and well-formed.

**Computation efficiency**:
I know that glm can be compiled (with optimization flags) to SIMD instructions, so I can gain a lot of speed by using the glm operators available instead of inventing my own. This way I won't have to struggle with intrinsics.

### The question

1. Is my intuition correct?
2. Is this a good way of tackling this problem / have you seen better solutions?
3. Can you make a guess at the efficiency of my implementation? (e.g. penalty of calling glm::vec2 constructors)

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: You're literally just reinventing GLM - you know that, right? Also GLM is just maths. If you want to switch to DirectX one day, most of GLM will still work for you.

Comment: @user253751 So you are implying that I'm creating a worse wrapper around something that already works out of the box for my purposes? Would you suggest, instead, that I could directly declare my types in the header as aliases for glm types? I'm not sufficiently experienced in knowing what would be _optimal_

Comment: If you want a type alias, you can declare `using vec2 = glm::vec2;`. But I would just use GLM until it doesn't work any more... if it doesn't work for some reason on DirectX, then you can always write your own DXM library and `namespace glm {using namespace dxm;}`

Comment: @alexpanter you can also use namespace alias `namespace glm=my_namespace`; I'm not sure polluting `glm` with `dxm` is a good decision.